# Are Validators pretending transaction already completed?

Tags: plutus, plutustx

A validator is called **prior** to transaction's start (not to mention completion). But yet a validator routinely checks if a potential recipient has **already** received his funds, and other such tests about events in the past.

So is the validator **pretending** that the transaction has already completed, whereas in truth the transaction has not yet started -- and perhaps never will?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a validator is called prior to the start of the transaction as it part of the constraints that determines if the transaction can proceed. A validator that executes on-chain has no visibility of past transactions. It can only see the transaction it belongs to, its inputs and input data supplied to the validator.
It is the off-chain code that constructs the transaction that has visibility of the full blockchain of past transactions.